# After I login to a server, I continuously fall through the ground.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I used to be able to play with my friend on their server and we could communicate and all that.

But now what happens is, I can log into their server, but then once I'm in, what I see from my end is me continuously falling into the ground and it's pitch black OR I get in, everything's there, my character's moving fine, but then my friend's character isn't moving, the mobsters aren't moving, I can't open things. And my friend says that, from her end, I'm not moving. We try logging in and out a few more times, but it's the same result.
So I don't understand what's going on - is that something wrong with my friend's server or is it something wrong with my computer?

Since the last time i was able to play on a server, i've had the video or graphics card or something replaced in my computer and I had been having some internet problems, could this be a factor?

Comment: Can you play on other servers okay? What version of minecraft are you running? Does anyone else play on her server, and do they have problems? Ask her to delete your profile info on the server (you'll lose any items and respawn in the original spawn location, however) and see if that does anything.

Comment: This point is unclear: are you having Internet problems now, or were those problems only before the something was replaced in your computer?

Answer (score 7):

**This is due to connectivity issues. You are "lagging out" so the server isn't receiving any response from your client and you aren't receiving any information from the server meaning nothing is happening.**

**Other players will see you just standing there, and you will see "nothing happening" despite everything that everyone else can see.** *If, like you have said, You are having internet issues try contacting your ISP (internet service provider, the company that provides you internet connection) and they should tell you if everything is ok on their end.* If they say everything is ok, you may have to replace your router (I recommend buying a decent one as an investment. Cheap ones tend to work for about 6 months and start declining in performance based on experience.).

**As stated by GOD_is_AFK__,** *you can restart your router and this will tend to temporarily solve the problem.* Also ensure that you don't have above 5 devices connected to the internet as it may slow down everything due to traffic.

**You can also try other servers to see if the same thing is happening.** *If it isn't, it is your friends connection.* If other people play the server, ask them what their connection is like (are they lagging?). If they are aswell, your friend may have to do what I have just stated above.

**Maybe try and run your own server and get them to connect to it and see if she then has the problems.**

Answer (score 3):

Try to restart your router (if you have one), that worked for me sometimes.